# Loop through action

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I am new to visual basic, however I need to loop through rows in a data table and use the values to in a test script, the script is as follows -

```vb
Public Function TestMain(ByVal args() As Object) As Object
    StartApp(URL)

    ' HTML Browser '
    Browser_HtmlBrowser(Document_HomePage(),DEFAULT_FLAGS).Maximize()

    Button_AddNewProfilesubmit().Click()

    'here is where the rows would be read and the loop would start'

    Text_Ctl00MainContentProfileNa().Click(AtPoint(6, 13))
    Browser_HtmlBrowser(Document_Http1921685526UserCon(), DEFAULT_FLAGS).InputChars("dataBase_Row_Value")
    Table_HtmlTable_1().Click(AtCell( _
                                    AtRow(AtIndex(0)), _
                                    AtColumn(AtIndex(1))))

    'here is where the loop would end after all rows had been read'

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

I have an idea to achieve this, first doing a database connection, then create the loop -

```vb
    Dim pName As String
    Dim datas As DataSet
    Dim datar As DataRow
    Dim oledat As SqlDataAdapter
    oledat = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COLUMN FROM DATABASE",ConnectionString)
    oledat.Fill(datas)
    For Each datar In datas.Tables(0).Rows
        pName = datar.Item("PROFILENAME")

        Text_Ctl00MainContentProfileNa().Click(AtPoint(6, 13))
        Browser_HtmlBrowser(Document_Http1921685526UserCon(), DEFAULT_FLAGS).InputChars(pName)
        Table_HtmlTable_1().Click(AtCell( _
                                    AtRow(AtIndex(0)), _
                                    AtColumn(AtIndex(1))))
    Next
```

However this is breaking, even though there are no errors in Visual Studio, there is only the warning that `datas` is used before it is assigned the values. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you say this is breaking what do you mean. Do you get an error when you run it? If so what is the error.

Comment: When debugging it doesn't run, it just says there were build errors, I  program in C# and if there is an error it will say so. I am using IBM's rational tester software to generate the scripts.

Comment: So What is the build error? You said you just had a warning above - this won't prevent it from compiling

Answer (score 1):

I believe you must initialize a new dataset before working with it.  Example:

```
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
Dim connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim command As OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim connString As String = "my Connection string stuff;"

connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString)
Try
    'open the connection
     If connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
     Else
          connection.Open()
     End If
     'fill each data table
     command = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(selectOne, connection)
     adapter.SelectCommand = command
     adapter.Fill(ds, "someTableName")
 Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
   'error, do something
 Finally
    'close everything down
    adapter.Dispose()
    If (Not command Is Nothing) Then
        command.Dispose()
    End If
    connection.Close()
End Try
```

This example uses OLEDB but should be comparable to what you are doing.  Once you fill it, you should be able to iterate over the tables.  But, first, check to make sure you have a dataset created first:

```
If (ds IsNot Nothing) Then
  'do for statement here
End If
```

If this does not work, let me know.